# ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED on nginx Raspberry Pi Home Server

Tags: ssl, nginx, web, raspberry-pi2

Basically, I have created a site and purchased an SSL certificate. Everything worked fine, I linked up the certificate in the config of the site, but then it suddenly stopped working. My linked site configuration, where I replaced my site with 'example.com', is as follows:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    return 301  https://example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    # Get SSL setup
    ssl                 on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/site.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/site.key;
    ssl_dhparam         /etc/nginx/ssl/dhparam.pem;
    ssl_session_timeout 1d;
    ssl_protocols       SSLv3 TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!3DES:!MD5:!PSK';
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_session_cache         shared:SSL:50m;

    # Enable HSTS ( see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security )
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=15768000;

    # OCSP Stapling
    ssl_stapling            on;
    ssl_stapling_verify     on;
    ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/site.crt;
    resolver                8.8.8.8;

    server_name www.example.com example.com;
    root /var/www/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    error_log /var/www/html/logs/error.log;
    access_log /var/www/html/logs/access.log;

    error_page 404 /404.html;

    location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Now, my site doesn't even work on a local IP address (192.168.1.x). Can someone please offer a solution?
Thank you.